# Error passing curl -d parameter in requests library

Tags: python, csv, curl, python-requests

I have a `curl` POST request that works perfectly in the terminal (macOS), returning a csv as expected.  The following format is provided in the RJMetrcis [documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/mbi/docs/export-api.html) (see "Export figure data").  Here is the curl request in bash:

```
 curl -d "format=csv&includeColumnHeaders=1" -H "X-RJM-API-Key: myAPIkey" https://api.rjmetrics.com/0.1/figure/0000/export
```

My objective is to implement the *exact* same curl request in Python using `requests`. When I input the same parameters as a POST request, the code does not work returning an error:

```
import requests


headers = {'X-RJM-API-Key: myAPIkey'}
data= {'format=csv&includeColumnHeaders=1'}
url = "https://api.rjmetrics.com/0.1/figure/0000/export"

response = requests.post(url, data, headers)
```

This returns the error:

```
TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

On the second try:

```
response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
```

returns

```
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items'
```

What is the correct format in python for constructing a POST request so that it matches the `data = {'key':'value'}` convention, and returns a csv?Any help would be appreciated translating the bash curl POST into a python POST request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are passing a set and you are expected to pass a dict or str object

```
data= {'format=csv&includeColumnHeaders=1'}
```

Replacing with

```
data= {'format':'csv&includeColumnHeaders=1'}
```

Should fix it.

On the other hand by seeing your curl request..

It all depends how you want to pass the data, following code (passing the data payload as a string) will post the data directly, that will be the equivalent to --data-raw in curl

```
import requests

url = "https://api.rjmetrics.com/0.1/figure/0000/export"

payload = "'{\"format\":\"csv&includeColumnHeaders=1\"}'"
headers = {
  'X-RJM-API-Key': 'myAPIkey'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

Comment: Thanks, this does return something, although it seems to return a json string

Comment: "outputs the data used to create the figure with the specified ID" from https://devdocs.magento.com/mbi/docs/export-api.html#export-figure-data
this is the json string you are getting? i think for getting a csv the api should have a GET request for that

Comment: Yes that is the JSON that is being returned