# cURL POST request not working as python requests equivalent

Tags: python, curl, post, python-requests

I have a `curl` POST request that returns a CSV in the terminal as expected.  The following format is provided in the RJMetrcis [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64147228/error-passing-curl-d-parameter-in-requests-library/64147414?noredirect=1#comment113434455_64147414) (see "Export figure data").  Here is the curl request in bash:

```
curl --data-raw "format=csv&includeColumnHeaders=1" -H "X-RJM-API-Key: myapikey" https://api.rjmetrics.com/0.1/figure/12345/export
```

Alternatively, using `-d` instead of `--data-raw` also works

However, when replicating this with the help of a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64147228/error-passing-curl-d-parameter-in-requests-library/64147414?noredirect=1#comment113434455_64147414) using `requests` in Python, an error is returned:

```
url = "https://api.rjmetrics.com/0.1/figure/12345/export"

payload = "'{\"format\":\"csv&includeColumnHeaders=1\"}'"
headers = {
  'X-RJM-API-Key': 'myapikey'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, params=payload)
response.text

'{"Error":"Invalid Argument: CSV is currently the only supported format for SQL Reports"}'
```

This is a specific error returned by the API indicating a CSV format is not requested (when `-d` is left out of the bash command, the same error is raised).  However, both requests are syntactically the same.  What could be the Python issue here? Is there a preferred method to pass parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import requests

data = {
    'format': 'csv',
    'includeColumnHeaders': 1
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0',
    'X-RJM-API-Key': 'yourapi'
}


def main(url):
    r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
    print(r)


main("https://api.rjmetrics.com/0.1/figure/12345/export")
```